# How to display only one record from child model for each header item in Django ListView using distinct()

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-views

I am using two related models in my Django application. The objects so created in the models are being displayed using the *listview* class. In the child model I can create multiple rows based on some key date. When I try to display values from both the models, all the child objects for the respective FK fields are displayed (wherever more than one records are there).

Let me make the situation clearer as below:

### models.py

```
class MatPriceDoc(models.Model):
    mat_price_doc_number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True.....)
    mat_num = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=.......)
    mat_group = models.ForeignKey(MatGrp, on_delete=.......)
    doc_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True, default='RF'....)
    create_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now,...)

class MatPriceItems(models.Model):
    price_doc_header = models.ForeignKey(MatPriceDoc, on_delete=...)
    price_item_num = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=10,...)
    price_valid_from_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='From date')
    price_valid_to_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='To date')
    mat_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True,...)
```

### views.py

```
class MatPriceListView(ListView):
    template_name = "mat_price_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'matprice'
    model = MatPriceDoc

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MatPriceListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'mat_price_item_list': MatPriceItems.objects.distinct().order_by('price_doc_header'),  #This is where I have tried **distinct()**
        })
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MatPriceDoc.objects.order_by('mat_num')
```

Now the material price changes periodically and there would always be more than one price item for each material for each key date (`price_valid_from_date`). My objective is to display the latest price of all those materials for which price documents exist. My predicament is how to pick up only one of the many price items for the same material / document combination. My code line `'mat_price_item_list': MatPriceItems.objects.distinct().order_by('price_doc_header'),` is of course **not yielding any result** (all price items are being displayed in successive columns).

**Is there a way to show only one price item in the listview?**

## Edit

In the following image the prices maintained for various dates for materials are shown. What I was trying to get was only the price for the latest (valid) date is displayed for a particular material. So in the instant case (as displayed), prices for only 4th March 2020 should be displayed for each item **MS** and **HSD**.

[image]

### Edit 2

This is how the child model data for an instance of header doc number (no. **32** here) looks like (image grab from the child table using data browser):

[image]

The columns are: **Child obj. item no.** / **Price** / **Valid From** / **Valid To** / **Hdr Doc no.** / **Child Obj Row no.**

**My thinking was**: Can I not pick up only the first object (a subset) from a collection of doc number? In the instant case (ref the image), doc no. **32** has three child items (bearing number **148**, **149** and **156**). Is it not possible to only pick up item number **156** and discard the rest?

I tried:

`MatPriceItems.objects.order_by('-price_valid_to_date').first()`

but raises **error** `"MatPriceItems" object is not iterable`.

**What would enable me to get the only item for a header item and display it?**

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I am using sqlite3 for test purposes.

Comment: Distinct will return all of the distinct records in the table, not one...perhaps you need to `order_by` then take the `.first()` to get the "maximum"?

Comment: Could you clarify what MS and HSD are please...

Comment: These are **materials** (`mat_num`). In actual practice there are material numbers but for test purposes I am using these (there are more than 10k variants). PS. Currently I am having a power failure, what a laugh!!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - There has been some discussion on the issue, yet unsolved. I have added some more info (esp. ref my **Edit 2**). Would like to get some advice on the matter.

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos: The comment addressing Mr. Van Onsem may pls be referred to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the following:

```
class MatPriceListView(ListView):
    template_name = "mat_price_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'matprice'
    model = MatPriceDoc

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MatPriceListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'mat_price_item_list': MatPriceItems.objects.all().('-price_doc_header').first(),
        })
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MatPriceDoc.objects.order_by('mat_num')
```

The key line change being:

```
MatPriceItems.objects.all().order_by('-price_doc_header').first()
```

Such that you order by the `price_doc_header` descending (hence the minus infront of that value). Then take the `.first()` in the returned `<QuerySet>` object.

Likewise, the following would also be valid:

```
MatPriceItems.objects.all().order_by('price_doc_header').last()
```

You could also make use of Django's built in aggregation in the ORM:

```
from django.db.models import Max

MatPriceItems.objects.all().aggregate(Max('price_doc_header'))
```

Putting this all together, I would say the best solution for readabiltiy of the code would be using Django's built-in `Max` function:

```
from django.db.models import Max

class MatPriceListView(ListView):
    template_name = "mat_price_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'matprice'
    model = MatPriceDoc

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MatPriceListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'mat_price_item_list': MatPriceItems.objects.all().aggregate(Max('price_doc_header'))
        })
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MatPriceDoc.objects.order_by('mat_num')
```

Because it tells any colleague exactly what you're doing: taking the maximum value.

**Update**: On a second glance of your question - I believe you may also need to do some sort of `.filter()`...then make an `.annotate()` for the `Max`...

Comment: Actually as I was trying to write my response(s), the edits came forth. Anyway, with the first solution, I was getting `"MatPriceItems" is not iterable`. I am sorry, but I don't understand the final edit from you with the code line `'mat_price_item_list': MatPriceItems.objects.all().aggregate(Max('price_doc_header'))`. With this the price values have simply vanished. I am not getting the `aggregate` and `Max` in the present scenario. Grateful for some inputs on this.

Comment: I've saved the neccessary changes. I missed `.all()` in my haste. Apologies. I also believe my second answer below is more approriate than this one...

Comment: @12379095 I believe tho if we could have a little discussion, I believe we can achieve what you need in one query...

Answer (score 0):

I'm also adding what I now believe is the correct answer based on a re-reading of your question.

I feel like the query needs to be ammended to:

```
MatPriceItems.objects.all().select_related(
    'mat_price_docs'
).order_by(
    'price_doc_header__mat_num'
)
```

i.e.,

```
class MatPriceListView(ListView):
    template_name = "mat_price_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'matprice'
    model = MatPriceDoc

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MatPriceListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({
            'mat_price_item_list': MatPriceItems.objects.all().select_related('mat_price_docs').order_by('price_doc_header__mat_num'),
        })
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MatPriceDoc.objects.order_by('mat_num')
```

To achieve this, you also add the `related_name` argument to the `price_doc_header` `ForeignKey` field.

```
class MatPriceItems(models.Model):
    price_doc_header = models.ForeignKey(MatPriceDoc, related_name='mat_price_docs', on_delete=...)
    price_item_num = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=10,...)
    price_valid_from_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='From date')
    price_valid_to_date = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='To date')
    mat_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True,...)
```

As always, any changes to your models - please re-run the `makemigarations` and `migrate` management commands.

**Edit**: You may even be able to define a new queryset using an annotation to link to the ForeignKey:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return MatPriceItems.objects.all().order_by(
                    'price_doc_header__mat_num'
               ).annotate(
                    mat_price_doc_number = F('price_doc_header__mat_price_doc_number')
                    ...
               )
```

N.B. You can import the F() expression as `from django.db.models import F`

Comment: Something is terribly wrong. I am getting `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'mat_price_docs'. Choices are: price_doc_header`. Just can't decipher.

Comment: **The result this time is the same** (as earlier in my original code) i.e. all the values of `mat_price` are appearing in successive columns against each header (`mat_price_doc_number`).

Comment: @12379095 I think you should maybe look at using an `annotate()`...do you need me to go further to explain this? See my edit to the above answer to see how an annotation is done.

Comment: **Please do so.**

Comment: @12379095 Added to my answer.

Comment: Strangely now I am getting only the item numbers of the child model (** MatPriceItems**). No other values are being displayed. I am sorry but I am not following it.

Comment: @12379095 That's ok - it's quite a high level topic. You need to add a field name for all of the annotations I believe.

Comment: But the result is missing (is what I meant by **not following**). PS. SO is now trying to send me to **chat room**...

Comment: What result is missing?

Comment: Like I said in "**strangely ...** above. By using your final solution only the child model's `id`;s are being displayed. Nothing else.

Comment: Is it ok to outline an example of what data you want to display ... just maybe in markdown format and how they correspond to your model's field names...